# SolrJ getFacetPivot is throwing error

Tags: solr, solrj, faceted-search

I am able get facet pivot values using solr query
http://app:8983/solr/test_shard1_replica1/select?wt=json&indent=true&q=*%3A*&facet=true&facet.pivot=categoryl0,categoryl1&start=0&rows=0

but not able to parse result using solrj 4.3 version, it has method getFacetPivot(), but it is throwing error.

I want to get count by grouping two fields

```
solarServer = getSolarServerConnection();    
try {
    SolrQuery parameters = new SolrQuery();
    parameters.setFacet(true);
    parameters.setFacetMinCount( 0 );
    parameters.setFacetMissing(true);
    parameters.setRows( 0 );
    parameters.add("q", "*:*");
    parameters.add("facet.pivot", "categoryl0,categoryl1");

    if(solarServer != null){
      queryResponse = solarServer.query(parameters);  
      Log.Info("Recieved response from solar successfully "  );
    }else{
      Log.Error("Unable to connect to solarServer...");
    }

    NamedList<List<PivotField>> pivots = queryResponse.getFacetPivot();
```

Comment: Please add the error which you are getting. Also you are using getFacetPivot() on the response received. So please check if you are getting any response in the first place. At a high level, you can add details regarding your actual requirement, so that others can suggest better ways. Happy coding and learning :)